# Django : calling the html page to display a list of object cannot be performed

Tags: django

Hi every one i'm new in Django and I'd like to display in a html page a list of object of test which is my class model and has two attributes which are testId and testName. Here is below my tree:

```
PyStack
 |
 |---PyStack (created with the command line "django-admin.py startproject PyStack"
 |     |---__init__.py
 |     |---settings.py
 |     |---urls.py
 |     |---wsgi.py
 |
 |---test (created manually and I added it in the setting.py file)
 |     |---templates
 |     |       |---test.html
 |     |---__init__.py
 |     |---test.py
 |
 |---vmm (created with the command line "python manage.py startapp vmm" 
 |     |---admin.py
 |     |---__init__.py
 |     |---models.py (which contains the test class model)
 |     |---tests.py
 |     |---views.py
 |
 |---manage.py
 |---db.sqlite3 (my database.I created one called "test" with two attribures testName and testId)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from test import test 


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test/',test.test,name="test",),
    url(r'^test2/',test.TestViewClass.as_view(),name="test",),
)
```

**test.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from vmm.models import TestModel


def test(x):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>hello</h1>")

class TestViewClass(ListView):
    model = TestModel
    template_name = "test.html"
```

**test.html:**

```
<h1>Hello Test From Django</h1>

<h1>Tests</h1>

<ul>
  {% for test in object_list %}
    <li>{{ test }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel(models.Model):

    testName = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    testId = models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    def __str__(self):

            return ' '.join([self.testName,self.testId,])
```

For the database , as you see , I used the SQLite 3 and the database contains one table called test.

the problem is when he calls the page to show the list of objects, it appears on me an error which is :
[image]

I also created another database called vmm_testmodel but it's the same error
thank you for your attention.

Comment: I would suggest working through the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ if you haven't already

Comment: You haven't initialized the database with "makemigrations" and "migrate" commands. Please read the first lesson of the Tutorial.

Comment: Use the admin application to see what is going on with your tables

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you haven't initialized your database, is that possible?
What version of Django do you use?

Try and run (Django 1.7 or newer)

```
./manage.py migrate
```

or (for older versions)

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

Source:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#syncdb

Comment: i have djanko 1.6.1 and i typed "./manage.py syncdb" but the same error still appear on me

Comment: @user3316482, please post the output of the following commands: `./manage.py runserver` and `./manage.py syncdb`

Comment: the problem is when I create a table and I close the sqlite shell after that I reopen it , the table which is created just before does not exist

Comment: ./manage.py runserver : root@rochdi:/home/rochdi/Desktop/PyStack# ./manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 27, 2015 - 15:28:58
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'PyStack.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: @rochdibouslama, what about the output of the syncdb command? Also please post your settings.py